# How to get the no of times a user visited a shop on each date(activity_date) from the model using a single query

Tags: django, database, orm

```
class StoreLog(models.Model):
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name=_('User'), related_name='user_analytics_data', null=True, blank=True)
    store_id = models.IntegerField(verbose_name=_('Store'))
    device_id = models.TextField(
        verbose_name=_("Device ID"), db_index=True,
        help_text=_("ANDROID_ID / TelephonyManager.getDeviceId() (always as hex)")
    )
    device_type = models.TextField(verbose_name=_("Device Info"), blank=True, null=True)
    activity_date = models.DateTimeField(_('Date'), default=timezone.now)
```

aim: if user visits a shop more than once on a particular date a mail should be send offering some deals

Comment: you have to create a new table to store the user visits

Comment: @ArpitSolanki Can you explain it a bit more?

Comment: create a table containing username datetime of visit then use aggregation queries to get if user has visited more than once in a day.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understand correctly that the StoreLog object is the record of an individual instance of a user visiting a store, you could query that table like so:

```
# Period of "the last 2 weeks"
start = datetime.datetime.now() - timedelta(days=14)
end = datetime.datetime.now()

visits = StoreLog.objects.filter(
    user_id=THEUSER,
    activity_date__range=[start, end],
)
```

This will return a queryset containing all of the StoreLogs that involve that particular user that occurred within the past 2 weeks.

To get the count, you just need to do

```
visit_count = visits.count()
```

From there, you can have a command do something like this to send off emails to users who meet your criteria:

```
# Period set to just one day
start = datetime.datetime.now() - timedelta(days=1)
end = datetime.datetime.now()

for user in User.objects.all():
    visits = StoreLog.objects.filter(
        user_id=user,
        activity_date__range=[start, end],
    )
    if visits.count() > 1:
        send_email_to_user(user)
```

To make it shop-specific, you'll also need to pass in the shop_id to the query criteria.

Comment: We could know the favourite store of a user by knowing that if the user instance has visited a particular store more than once during the period we set, and the email that we send should notify him of his favourite store deals/offers